# Is the Range header the size in bytes of the compressed or uncompressed bytes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, webserver

I'm implementing static file serving in node.js for learning and fun. Let's say I am sending a file called `party-time.txt` which is:

```
100 bytes uncompressed

70 bytes gzipped
```

If the user requests `Range: bytes=-10`, is this request for the last 10 uncompressed bytes (e.g., 91-100) or is it the last 10 compressed bytes (e.g., 61-70)?

Answer (score 2):

> HTTP retrieval requests using conditional or unconditional GET methods MAY request one or more sub-ranges of the entity, instead of the entire entity, using the Range request header, *which applies to the entity returned as the result of the request*.

[14.35.2 Range Retrieval Requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2)

Because the actual entity returned from the request is the gzip encoded data, that data is used to derive the Content-Length and therefore the Range is applied against that.

Answer (score 1):

As part of the HTTP protocol, you should be specifying the Content-Encoding as well as the Content-Length.  The content length should match the length of the file relative to your encoding technique.  For example, if you set your Content-Encoding to gzip, the range of bytes that the user requests should be a request for the compressed length.

Packet example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: mon, 28 Aug 2015 22:38:34 GMT
Server: <Your server>
Last-Modified: mon, 28 Aug 2015 22:38:34 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 438
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
```